# Why do electrophillic addition reactions (between hydrogen halides and alkenes) happen?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, halides

I understand that the type of solvent (protic or aprotic) may impact the rate of the reaction, but why doesn't the hydrogen just stick with the halide in the first place?

I'm not sure if the reason is just that the hydrogen's electrophilic attraction to the π orbital electrons are just stronger than the hydrogen's electrostatic attraction to the electrons it shared with the halide.

Am I missing something?